# Is there a JPA or Hibernate file store that works like Play Framework Blob

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, playframework

Reference to Play Framework Blob

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/jpa

When you store a file in play, it stores the files in a separate folder and just saves a reference to that file in the database. So it's not storing the file inside the database itself, I don't think it's creating a separate table to manage the files(I could be wrong).

Is there something similar to this in vanilla JPA (As play uses JPA). I am writing a new Spring project using MySQL and Hibernate(<- negotiable).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't get the question. Choose a file where to store the uploaded data, save the data to the file, and store the file path into your table using JPA. Where's the problem?

Comment: I'm more looking not to re-invent the wheel. If something is already supported by JPA or Hibernate I don't want to go against the standard.  I thought to myself if the Play! framework is already doing this, and it has to be something that everyone does all the time. If those things are true how could it be that there is no standard way to handle this. Not that I think it would take that long to implement, but lots of useful utilities wouldn't.

Comment: Also I need to go looking for what is the best location to store these files in a cross-platform way.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not such a filestore in JPA, and also not in Hibernate. JPA's scope is quite strictly mapping between objects and database tables and querying mapped objects.